# while using ivi drivers in python, unable to "import pyivi"

Tags: python

New to python. I've installed python 3.7.2. I'm interested to control lab instruments using python ivi (pyivi). 
using pip, I've installed pyivi and all dependences (pip install python-ivi)
after all installion I can import ivi but not pyivi
so basically import ivi works 
but when I tried to import pyivi, then got the following exception:

> import pyivi
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       import pyivi
>     File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pyivi__init__.py", line 1, in 
>       import ivic
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ivic'

any idea, what I'm doing wrong?

installed python
installed ivi
installed pyivi
installed comtpyes

Comment: Why not `pip install pyivi`? (https://pypi.org/project/pyivi/)

Comment: Have tried this with same results, i.e  import ivic ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ivic'